# How to establish the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am trying to solve the following question but I do not understand how the first equality sign is established.
[image]

Why does the first equality apply with the negative sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person who wrote that question probably wanted you to use the Implicit Function Theorem. Here's the statement of the theorem.

Let $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous differentiable function. Suppose that for some point $(x_0,y_0)$, we have that $\partial_y F(x_0,y_0) \neq 0$ and that $F(x_0,y_0) = c$. Then, there is a nbhd of $(x_0,y_0)$ such that if $x$ is sufficiently close to $x_0$, then there is a unique $y$ such that $F(x,y) = c$.

So far, this doesn't actually say anything about the differentiability of $y$ per se. But now, if we just use the chain rule and the following heuristic using differentials, we obtain:
$$dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} \ dx + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} \ dy$$
In this case, $dF = 0$ when we're considering the points where $F(x,y) = c$. Dividing by $dx$, we obtain that:
$$0 = \partial_1 F(x,y) + \partial_2 F(x,y) \ y'_c(x)$$
But this means that:
$$y'_c(x) =-\frac{\partial_1 F(x,y)}{\partial_2 F(x,y)}$$
Again, I should emphasize that the above is to be taken as a heuristic and this isn't how you actually prove the Implicit Function Theorem. The actual argument for that is a lot more elaborate. Now, the idea here is that you should apply the above to your one-parameter family of functions $\Gamma_c$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly it! I just missed a few steps I see now.

Comment: No problem at all :D

Comment: There exist  a function z: x->z(x) such that the graph of $y_{c}$ and z intersect at a right angle. I have to show that this z satisfies the ODE $z'(x) = \frac{-2x}{z(x)}$
Would you now how to get started on this? I can easily solve the ODE but have a hard time showing how it came to be.

Comment: Start by considering what you can say about their slopes.

Comment: I am trying to use the fact that the scalar product of the two tangent vectors should be zero but I am not setting up the right expressions for the vectors.